# Algebraic subgroups $ H $ of $ G $ such that $ H(k) = G(k) $

Tags: algebraic-groups

The following theorem can be found in Milne's [book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/algebraic-groups/48D122BAEC63C2B70304E20F34482C8F) on algebraic groups (Theorem 1.45) and in his [online course notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf) (Proposition 1.31):

**Theorem:** Let $G$ be an algebraic group (= algebraic group scheme, not necessarily affine) over a field $ k $ and $S$ a closed subgroup of $G(k)$. Then there is a unique reduced algebraic subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $ H(k) = S$.

From this I deduce:

**Corollary:** Let $G$ be a reduced algebraic group over a field $ k $ and let $H$ be a reduced algebraic subgroup of $G$ such that $ H(k) = G(k) $. Then $ H = G $.

*Proof:* Apply the Theorem with $ S = G(k) $.

However:

**Counterexample to the Corollary:** Let $k$ be the field of real numbers and let $G=\mu_3$ be the group of 3rd roots of unity (i.e. the Hopf algebra of $G$ is $k[X]/(X^3-1)$). Since $k$ is of characteristic zero, $G$ is smooth and thus reduced. Let $ H $ be the trivial subgroup of $G$ (i.e. $H(R) = \{1\} $ for all $k$-algebras $R$). Then $ H(k) = \{1\} = G(k) $ and $G,H$ are both reduced, but $G \neq H$.

Where is my mistake?

(If it helps, I only care about affine group schemes.)

Comment: In the latest version (rough preliminary version 2017) on Milne's homepage this is changed. In section 1c these are Corollary $1.32$, $1.33$ and so on. I cannot find your result above anymore. In particular, section 1c has no Theorem $1.45$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I edited my question to clarify the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deduction in the question and the example are correct, but the Theorem is wrong. This is listed in the [Errata](https://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/iagerrata.html) for the book. The correct version of the theorem should be that, under the same assumptions, there exists a unique reduced algebraic subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $ |H| = \overline{S} $, where $|H|$ is the underlying topological space of $H$ and $ \overline{S} $ is the Zariski closure of $S$ in $G$. This algebraic subgroup $H$ satisfies $ H(k) = |H| \cap G(k) = \overline{S} \cap G(k) = S $, but it is not necessarily uniquely determined by the property $ H(k) = S $. Thus the Corollary stated in the question is not correct in this general form.